# LEFT JOIN EXISTS

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, `Main` and `Details` - they have a one-to-many relationship, with one row in `Main` potentially having multiple rows in `Details`.

I am trying to create a query that returns all the information from `Main`, plus the whether the associated rows in `Details` contain one of a set of codes.  Of course, since it's a one-to-many, there may be several of those codes present in `Details` - and I don't want to double count rows.  I need to do it a couple of times over, too.

What I kind of want is something like this:

```
SELECT m.*, CASE WHEN x.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Codes1, CASE WHEN y.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Codes2
FROM [Main] m
LEFT JOIN EXISTS(SELECT d.ID FROM [Details] d WHERE m.ID = d.ID AND d.Code IN (<<Codes1>>)) x
LEFT JOIN EXISTS(SELECT d.ID FROM [Details] d WHERE m.ID = d.ID AND d.Code IN (<<Codes2>>)) y
```

Is there some way to do this?  (This seems something that should be obvious and I'm overcomplicating to the nth degree, but I'm genuinely drawing a blank...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `EXISTS` from your query and add a `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   m.*, 
   CASE WHEN x.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Codes1, 
   CASE WHEN y.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Codes2 
FROM [Main] m 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.ID FROM [Details] d WHERE m.ID = d.ID AND d.Code IN (<<Codes1>>)) x 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.ID FROM [Details] d WHERE m.ID = d.ID AND d.Code IN (<<Codes2>>)) y
```

Comment: use of DISTINCT is discouraged because it hits performance pretty hard..

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT  M.*, 
        CASE WHEN C1.Codes IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Codes1,
        CASE WHEN C2.Codes IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Codes2
FROM    Main M
LEFT
JOIN    
(
    SELECT  d.Id,
            COUNT(d.Code) as Codes
    FROM    Details d
    WHERE   d.Code in (<<Codes1>>)
    GROUP 
    BY      d.Id
) C1
    ON C1.Id = M.Id
LEFT
JOIN    
(
    SELECT  d.Id,
            COUNT(d.Code) as Codes
    FROM    Details d
    WHERE   d.Code in (<<Codes2>>)
    GROUP 
    BY      d.Id
) C2
    ON C2.Id = M.Id
```

If you don't need the M.* then this might be better:

```
SELECT  M.Id, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN D1.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Codes1Count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN D2.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Codes2Count
FROM    Main M
LEFT
JOIN    Details D1
        ON  D1.Id = M.Id 
        AND D1.Code in (<<Codes1>>)
LEFT
JOIN    Details D2
        ON  D2.Id = M.Id 
        AND D2.Code in (<<Codes2>>)
GROUP 
BY      M.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slim version of code that will get you what you want

```
SELECT abb1.*, abb2.mycount 
FROM Main AS abb1
    JOIN (SELECT Main.ID, COUNT(Details.ID) AS mycount
         FROM Main 
            JOIN Details on Details.ID = Main.ID
         GROUP BY Main.ID) AS abb2
```